# How can i treat UserNotFound exception on endpoints unit tests?

Tags: java, api, rest, unit-testing, junit

I'm working on a spring boot CRUD RESTful API with an *User* entity that consists of two parameters : `name` and `id`. My test framework is **JUnit**.

The problem i'm facing is that i don't know how to treat a throwable *UserNotFound* exception on my services unit tests.

I have possible *"User not found by {id}"* exceptions in my *"List user by id"*, *"Delete user by id"* and *"Update user by id"* as you can see (i'll only list two endpoints to make this shorter) :

```
@Service
public class DeleteUserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = repository.findById(id);
        if (!userOptional.isPresent()) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(id);
        } else {
            repository.deleteById(id);
        }
    }
}

@Service
public class DetailUserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public Optional<User> listUser(Long id) {

        Optional<User> user = repository.findById(id);
        if (!user.isPresent()) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(id);
        } else {
            return repository.findById(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing wrong so far, my endpoints are working fine.
The *UserNotFound* code is :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class UserNotFoundAdvice {

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(UserNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    String userNotFoundHandler(UserNotFoundException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}

public class UserNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public UserNotFoundException(Long id) {
        super("Could not find user with id " + id + ".");
    }
}
```

The unit tests (the main reason this is being written) :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DeleteUserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private DeleteUserService deleteUserService;

    @Test
    public void whenGivenId_shouldDeleteUser_ifFound(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(89L);

        deleteUserService.deleteUser(user.getId());
        verify(userRepository).deleteById(user.getId());
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DetailUserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private DetailUserService detailUserService;

    @Test
    public void whenGivenId_shouldReturnUser_ifFound() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(89L);

        Optional<User> userMock = Optional.of(user);

        when(userRepository.findById(user.getId())).thenReturn(userMock);

        Optional<User> expected = detailUserService.listUser(user.getId());

        assertThat(expected).isSameAs(userMock);
        verify(userRepository).findById(user.getId());
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's something missing in these unit tests code which is the behavior of the *UserNotFound*. Perhaps it is not properly mocked or something else's missing in the unit tests code??

Would really appreciate if someone could help me with this one! Sorry if the post's too long, i tried my best to explain it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you need to test the behavior when the user is not found and you throw an exception.

Here is the link about how to test exception: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-assert-exception

And also additionally you can verify that delete by id or find by id weren't invoked:

```
verify(userRepository, never()).findById(user.getId()); 
or
verify(userRepository, Mockito.times(0)).findById(user.getId());
```

and for the deleteById the same

To test that exception handlers were invoked and worked correctly you need integration tests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i still couldn't find a way to make this work. I'm getting the org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations error message on my unit test.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with this : Optional<User> user = repository.findById(id);
        if (!user.isPresent()) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(id);
        }